# VAT included price on PayPal

Tags: paypal

I'm in the UK, where we normally tell our customers prices which include VAT, and then only mention how much VAT has been paid on the receipt.

I'm setting up a site at the moment which accepts payments using PayPal, and I'd really like to be able to pass PayPal the price including VAT and have it calculate how much of that price is tax, rather than pass the price excluding VAT and have it added on, which is the default behaviour I'm seeing.

Obviously I could display VAT inclusive prices on my site, calculate a VAT exclusive price, pass that to PayPal, and then let them add the VAT back on again. I'd rather not do this though, as it would mean that

1. I have to store what the VAT rate is in my site. I'd like to keep my round figure prices even if the VAT rate changes.
2. I could get rounding errors taking the VAT off, and then letting PayPal add it back on again (I guess it may be possible to pass PayPal a price which is not in whole pence).

Have I missed some way of setting this in the PayPal documentation?

Comment: I'm not really convinced a question about how to use an API, and to avoid rounding errors is not about programming. Oh well.

Comment: The [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) states "... if your question generally covers:
 + a specific programming problem
 + a software algorithm
 + software tools commonly used by programmers
 + practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession
… then you’re in the right place to ask your question!"
This question should be re-opened.

Comment: 3 years later i find myself struggling with calculating the VAT, any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

No, this is not possible.
You can either send the total amount incl. VAT, split total excl VAT and have VAT added separately or send the total excl VAT and have PayPal add it.
What you want is not possible.

Comment: Sadly, that's the conclusion I've come to too. Another possible solution I wondered about was passing in fractional pence, but these are not accepted. This makes PayPal's VAT stuff basically useless for a UK shop. Sigh.

Comment: Do you know how i can split the total excl VAT and have VAT added separately. Because when i have more digits i get an error message and using round doesn;t work